# Deploying contract via Remix costs less gas than deploying via javascript

Tags: remix, contract-deployment, gas, gas-limit

When I launch my contract via remix, it launches with no issues.
When I try to launch the contract via my javascript web3, using the same gas price and gas limit, it fails b/c it ran out of gas.

This was sent by my javascript
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x27bc68deb0323086d440df5b1daa5aeaf25790b096d4fa492188268294a394c7

This was launched with Remix
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x15887ebca7e6204e32c98fd600d3b0c695b75e31d48ba3785789ef687b3b3cc8

Comment: Look at the input data for those two calls. It is very obvious they are not doing the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the tx data for those two transactions. The one from Remix looks like a full contract, but the one from javascript doesn't look like it's deploying a contract.

Comment: Yes I finally realized that I need to send just the byte code object and not the entire bytecode copied from remix.